# matrix.postTranslate is not working in Tablet 10 inch

Tags: android, uiimageview

I have been making an app in which I have imageview and I am rotating , scaling and dragging images in it. ON touch every thing was working perfectly. But ther was a problem . and that is , due to my app requiremtnt I wanted to set the image at the bottom of the screen where as by setting the scaletype to matrix was not letting the image to stick to the position which was desired

but then some one give me very nice solution  and that is as below

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

                Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
                Rect rectDrawable = drawable.getBounds();

                float leftOffset = (imageView.getMeasuredWidth() - rectDrawable.width()) / 2f;
                float topOffset = (imageView.getMeasuredHeight() - rectDrawable.height()) / 1f;

                 matrix = imageView.getImageMatrix();
                Log.d("pixels_are",leftOffset+"top"+topOffset+"matrix"+matrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(leftOffset, topOffset);
                imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        });
```

this was setting the image to the bottom of the screen, then When I tested this code on the 10 inch tablets it is again setting the image at the top of screen

I do not know why it is only happening on 10 inch tablet whereas it is running on the 7 inch tablet  and other devices.

So what should I do ? what is a main reason of it ?

**Update1: ** 
***10' device log***
the imageview size is  800 in width and 1232px . I got this through

> imageView.getMeasuredWidth() and imageView.getMeasuredHeight()

next thing is offset and top thorugh the code I am getting the 
leftOffset = 40.5  and topOffset = 610.0 
and the matrix is {[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

***7' device log***

in 7 inch each and every thing is working , rotation , scaling and dragging and the logs are as below

the imageview size is  800 in width and 1280px . I got this through

> imageView.getMeasuredWidth() and imageView.getMeasuredHeight()

next thing is offset and top thorugh the code I am getting the 
leftOffset = -78.5  and topOffset = 452.0 
and the matrix is {[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

Comment: What is the output of your Log statement? 

Also print the measured width and height of the device to log to see how they differ between the two devices. My guess is that there is some division issue, based on the screen size difference. You can have all sorts of resolutions going on a 10 inch tablet... 

Also, please explain the use of division with 1 in topOffset? Why divide with 1.00 as that would give the same result as before no?

Comment: `"but then some one give me very nice solution"` i don't think so

Comment: oh haha @pskink that was working , do you have any

Comment: @RichardEriksson let me update my question with logs

Comment: use `Matrix.setRectToRect`

Comment: @pskink please tell me where should I use this line and how

Comment: inside `onGlobalLayout`

Comment: oked thanks I did it